# Running C# code fails only in release build (probably because of JIT compiler optimization)

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit

The code below runs successfully in debug build, but is stalled after displaying "start" in release build.
As long as I've looked into it, it seems to take a lot of time to compile the method in JIT compiler with optimization.

Why is it stalled and what is the work around?

I checked with visual studio 2017 community edition.

**Edited:**
It fails only when CPU=AnyCPU(remove prefer 32bit) or CPU=x64.

I just installed .Net Framework 4.7.1. (Target framework is .Net Framework 4.)
Even after installed .Net Framework 4.7.1, the problem still exists.

After setting useLegacyJit to the registry, it was solved. (when remove useLegacyJit, the problem came again.) It seems to be the bug with the RyuJIT.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("start");
            Calculation calc = new Calculation();
            calc.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }
    }

    class Calculation
    {
        double[] V0 = new double[1];
        double[] V1 = new double[1];
        double[] V2 = new double[1];
        double[] V3 = new double[1];
        double[] V4 = new double[1];
        double[] V5 = new double[1];
        double[] V6 = new double[1];
        double[] V7 = new double[1];
        double[] V8 = new double[1];
        double[] V9 = new double[1];
        double[] V10 = new double[1];
        double[] V11 = new double[1];
        double[] V12 = new double[1];
        double[] V13 = new double[1];
        double[] V14 = new double[1];
        double[] V15 = new double[1];
        double[] V16 = new double[1];
        double[] V17 = new double[1];
        double[] V18 = new double[1];
        double[] V19 = new double[1];
        double[] V20 = new double[1];
        double[] V21 = new double[1];
        double[] V22 = new double[1];
        double[] V23 = new double[1];
        double[] V24 = new double[1];
        double[] V25 = new double[1];
        double[] V26 = new double[1];
        double[] V27 = new double[1];
        double[] V28 = new double[1];
        double[] V29 = new double[1];
        double[] V30 = new double[1];
        double[] V31 = new double[1];
        double[] V32 = new double[1];
        double[] V33 = new double[1];
        double[] V34 = new double[1];
        double[] V35 = new double[1];
        double[] V36 = new double[1];
        double[] V37 = new double[1];
        double[] V38 = new double[1];
        double[] V39 = new double[1];
        double[] V40 = new double[1];
        double[] V41 = new double[1];
        double[] V42 = new double[1];
        double[] V43 = new double[1];
        double[] V44 = new double[1];
        double[] V45 = new double[1];
        double[] V46 = new double[1];
        double[] V47 = new double[1];
        double[] V48 = new double[1];
        double[] V49 = new double[1];

        public void Run()
        {
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V0[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V1[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V2[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V3[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V4[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V5[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V6[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V7[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V8[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V9[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V10[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V11[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V12[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V13[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V14[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V15[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V16[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V17[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V18[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V19[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V20[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V21[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V22[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V23[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V24[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V25[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V26[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V27[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V28[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V29[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V30[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V31[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V32[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V33[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V34[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V35[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V36[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V37[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V38[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V39[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V40[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V41[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V42[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V43[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V44[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V45[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V46[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V47[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V48[x] = 0.0;}
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){V49[x] = 0.0;}
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Steve thank you for checking, did you run successfully in release build with code optimization?

Comment: Just the default Optmize Code is set. However I have checked again and I can reproduce now with Target CPU = AnyCPU but removing the Prefer 32bit flag.

Comment: @Steve: I have the same here.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to fail only when CPU=AnyCPU(remove prefer 32bit) or CPU=x64.

Comment: You need to identify more details. If it fails on your machine when the process runs as 64 bit, it could be a RyuJIT issue, like https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1296, because when running as 32 bit, RyuJIT is not used. Also check the .NET Framework version installed on your machine, and test other versions if possible, as Microsoft might have fixed it in latest 4.7.1 already.

Comment: Indeed seems to be the bug with the RyuJIT, if it's disabled via `Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework -Name useLegacyJit -Type DWord -Value 1` the issue is gone.

Comment: Thank you all, I added some details on the post.

Comment: @threecourse I've run your example against master build of the `coreclr`, and it seems that they have solved the problem. The offending method probably was [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/180a3c80b1d193f4c63b265e21bd29277b81cbcd/src/jit/valuenum.cpp#L1374) one.

Comment: @Alex Do you mean that they have solved the problem in .NET Core, so they will also fix in .Net Framework in a while?

Comment: @threecourse It shoud be released as part of the .NET Core 2.1 sometimes in Q1, not sure about .NET Framework though. I'll write my observations in an answer to serve for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed seems to be an issue with RyuJIT, which can be verified by temporarily disabling it:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework -Name useLegacyJit -Type DWord -Value 1`

Tracking the actual issue down is a bit more involved, however, if we build [coreclr v2.0.5](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) (latest stable), and run it with `/v` verbose flag and with `COMPlus_JitDump=*` Environment variable set, after some time it starts printing out a lot of logs like this one:

> ```
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$277]store($dae, $1c0, $276), $f5b) ==> select($dae, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$277]store($dae, $1c0, $276), $f5b) ==> select($dae, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$279]store($dbd, $1c0, $278), $f5b) ==> select($dbd, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$277]store($dae, $1c0, $276), $f5b) ==> select($dae, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$277]store($dae, $1c0, $276), $f5b) ==> select($dae, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$279]store($dbd, $1c0, $278), $f5b) ==> select($dbd, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$27b]store($e0f, $1c0, $27a), $f5b) ==> select($e0f, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$27d]store($e21, $1c0, $27c), $f5b) ==> select($e21, $f5b).
>   AX2: $f5b != $1c0 ==> select([$27f]store($e32, $1c0, $27e), $f5b) ==> select($e32, $f5b).
> ```

The method printing the log can be found at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.0.5/src/jit/valuenum.cpp#L1377

The issue is most likely caused by `budget` variable overflowing or otherwise not reducing for some reason. Unfortunately, haven't had much time to investigate it further, but some changes to that method have been made [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/commit/3fc07ad6ffcb49646d629ba63b6f156a7071c2eb), and when I tried running the sample with [master](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/jit/valuenum.cpp#L1374) build of Core CLR the probleem seems to have been solved.

As per [Roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md), it's due for release in Q1 2018. I'm not sure when is this going to be included in the actual .NET Framework release though.

As a workaround, perhaps you can try refactoring the loops into their own methods:

```
public void RunLoop(double[] arr)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        arr[x] = 0.0;
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Which seems to solve the issue as well (if it makes sense to do that in your actual code).

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer!